# Print the elements in an array having character 'a'

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

How do we write code to print elements containing 'a' in myarray

```
myarray = np.array([
  [['car','jeep','bus'],['cat','dog','rat']],
  [['apple','orange','banana'],['London','New York','Paris']]
])
```

I have tried using this method but I did not get any output.

```
import numpy as np
myarray = np.array([
  [['car','jeep','bus'],['cat','dog','rat']],
  [['apple','orange','banana'],['London','New York','Paris']]
])     
         
for i in range(0, len(myarray)):    
    print(i[0])
    if 'i' in myarray:
        print(myarray[0])
    else:
        continue
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using Numpy and not plain python lists? Having an array of strings, then looping over them suggest Numpy might not be the right tool here.

Answer (score 0):

**[Credit](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/ic7s4b/traversing_an_arbitrarily_nested_list/)** You don't need NumPy in this situation.
Below is an example of how you can traverse a deeply nested list and return each element.

```
x = [[['car','jeep','bus'],['cat','dog','rat']],[['apple','orange','banana'],['London','New York','Paris']]]
def traverse(a):
    if not isinstance(a, list):yield a
    else:
        for e in a:yield from traverse(e)
aWords = [string for string in [e for e in traverse(x)] if 'a' in string]
```

**output**

```
['car', 'cat', 'rat', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'Paris']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with `numpy.char.find`.

```
np.char.find(myarray, 'a')
```

The output indicates the position where the character is found, or otherwise -1 if the character is absent:

```
array([[[ 1, -1, -1],
    [ 1, -1,  1]],

   [[ 0,  2,  1],
    [-1, -1,  1]]])
```

The following returns the elements where 'a' was found:

```
myarray[np.char.find(myarray, 'a') > -1]
```

Which gives the output:

```
array(['car', 'cat', 'rat', 'apple', 'orange', 'banana', 'Paris'],
  dtype='<U8')
```

Comment: `np.char.find` gives -1 for the elements where 'a' is absent. `np.char.find` gives 0 if the character occurs at position 0, 1 if it occurs at position 1 etc. To select the elements that contain the character 'a', it selects all values larger than -1.

Comment: Thank you so much, Sir. Your answer helped me.